# Why does Qt reject a valid JSON?

Tags: c++, json, qt

Using Qt-5.0, I have this JSON string

```
{"type":"FILE"}
```

I expected that `fromBinaryData` accept `.toLocal8Bit()` of the string as a valid format but it doesn't.

```
QString j = "{\"type\":\"FILE\"}";

auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(j.toLocal8Bit());

doc.isNull() // It's true, means the entry is not valid
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: did you tried: `QByteArray j = "{\"type\":\"FILE\"}";`? Maybe conversion is not proper.

Comment: try also `QJsonDocument::fromJson(const QByteArray & json, QJsonParseError * error = 0)` to get information what is the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have no idea of Qt, so I googled for a second. [Here's what I found](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html#fromBinaryData):

What you have is a string, a text representation. It's not the binary format Qt uses internally. The binary data would not be readable. `QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData` expects such a binary blob.

What you want to do seems to be achieved with `QJsonDocument::fromJson` which expects an UTF8-encoded Json string.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `fromBinaryData` use `fromJson` with the same argument, I had this exact problem yesterday and that was what worked for me.